# How can I convert text typed in an input box to lower case?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to convert the text typed into a text input box (txtQuestion) into all lower case, i.e. typing "input" or "INpUt" will be read the same and output the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [toLowerCase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) function. Eg: `"INPuT".toLowerCase();`

```js
exampleFunction = function(){

  //First we get the value of input
  var oldValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
  
  //Second transform into lowered case
  var loweredCase = oldValue.toLowerCase();
  
  //Set the new value of input
  document.getElementById('input').value = loweredCase;
  
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" onkeyup="exampleFunction()" />
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where to put the toLowerCase() function so that it will convert input typed into a text box by the user.

Comment: @SamC See this new example that i made, showing where you can use this

Comment: @SamC If it was what you wanted, mask as right answer to help future people with the same doubt

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the events that you want to watch and then return to the input the same value but lowercase:

```js
function InputLowerCaseCtrl(element, event) {
  console.log(element.value)
  return element.value = (element.value || '').toLowerCase();
};

InputLowerCaseCtrl.bindTo = ['blur'].join(' ');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('.input-lowercase');
  return input.addEventListener(InputLowerCaseCtrl.bindTo, InputLowerCaseCtrl.bind(this, input));
});
```

```html
<input class="input-lowercase" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any string input to lowercase using the String.prototype.toLowerCase function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

For you example with an input for txtQuestion.

```js
var inputStringLowerCase = inputTxtQuestion.value.toLowerCase();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fbkq2po4/